# Dead Rising 3 crashing on Windows 10

Tags: technical-issues, windows-10, dead-rising-3

Dead Rising 3 seems to crash after 10 minutes or so. There are a few bits of information on this elsewhere on the web, but none of the solutions seem conclusive. I've tried running the game in administrator mode and with windows 8 compatibility mode set, but no luck. Any known solutions to this?  I'm using a Win 10 machine using an Nvidia 770 with an Intel i7 CPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by a user on reddit named rickyshea

1. Press Ctrl + Shift + Esc to open up Windows Task Manager.
2. Scroll down and search for a process called "Touch Keyboard and Handwriting Panel" or "TabTip.exe".
3. Right click on the process and click "End Task".
4. Launch Dead Rising 3.

This should resolve the issue.  (Additionally, this works for the exact same crash in Street Fighter 5)

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling it if nothing works. Also verify game cache (if you have on steam), and check files. I have the same game, and this happened to me once. Putting it on Windows 8 Compatibility mode fixed it. So yeah, those are my solutions

Comment: 'Try reinstalling' may be the most standard "solution" or tip I have ever read on SE (which may be a solution if there is evidence that this really fixes something). Also, "verify game cache" and "check files", what do you mean by that? Check which files, for what? You should update your answer with some more details.